# Understanding a step in a proof on diagnosability of graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am currently writing a paper about diagnosability of graphs. For this, I am looking into a paper published in 1967 by Preparata, Metze and Chien called "[On The Connection Assignment Problem of Diagnosable Systems](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/handle/2142/74464)".

I am currently working through the proof of Theorem 5 within this paper and there is one step that I just can't understand. In the link above, this step happens right at the top of page 22 with the sentence:

> The above stated condition (1) can be met if the number $n$ of units cannot be partitioned in less than $s$ sequences of the given maximum length.

Why is this true?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include some of the relevant definitions and statements in your question, to save people having to look through the whole of the article that you are referring to

Comment: You're definitely right about that, but the definitions come from an algorithm further up in the paper, so it is very hard to summarize all of those in just one post.

Comment: Hmm, is diagnosability of graphs related to the [graph isomorphism disease](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jgt.3190010410)?  (I thought for sure it was a typo for 'diagonalisable', but it appears not!)

Answer (score 1):

I think I just solved it myself, so I'm just gonna put the answer here:

I ended up reshuffling the proof and using two properties. One is equation (3) from the same proof. The other property is
$$s \ r_{max} \geq n,$$

which is true because we have split $n$ into $s$ segments of maximum length $r_{max}$. Then we can combine the two properties to get (1).